# ¿Se puede considerar una rima asonante como consonante?

Tags: poesía, rima

En una copla en la que cada verso par tiene rima asonante, si la rima en dos de ellos que van uno a continuación del otro (6-8) es consonante, ¿se podría considerar como asonante para no romper la estructura del poema?

Answer (score 3):

En temas de poesía, más que autoridades lo que hay son opiniones...
Dicho lo cual, en mi opinión **no se puede considerar asonante una rima consonante**.

Las rimas se basan en el sonido, y los tipos de estrofa en el ritmo que la rima impone.
Una rima consonante no imprime el mismo ritmo y sonoridad que una asonante, por tanto no valdría usar rima consonante para montar una estrofa que debe contener rima asonante.

Por ejemplo, una [*seguidilla*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seguidilla_(poes%C3%ADa)) es un tipo de estrofa que tiene rima asonante. Si compones una estrofa con la misma métrica pero con rima consonante, aunque siga rimando, no suena igual, y por tanto eso ya no es una *seguidilla*.